# Asp.net core and Entityframwork migration error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have models folder and in folder i have **Todo.cs** and **TodoContext.cs**

In **Todo.cs** my code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ApiCrudWithEfCore.Models
{
    public class Todo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public bool Iscomplete { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And in TodoContext i have :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ApiCrudWithEfCore.Models
{
    public class TodoContext : DbContext
    {
        public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options) :base(options) {}

        public DbSet<Todo> Todos { get; set; }

    }
}
```

After that i put my connection string in **appsettings.json** :

> {
>    connection: "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Todo;Trusted_Connection=True;",
>     "Logging": {
>       "LogLevel": {
>         "Default": "Warning"
>       }
>     },
>     "AllowedHosts": "*"
>   }

And i use it in startup.cs like this:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services,IConfiguration config)
        {

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("connection")));
        }
```

But when i use Add-Migration command it give me this error:

> An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'.
>   Continuing without the application service provider. Error: The
>   ConfigureServices method must either be parameterless or take only one
>   parameter of type IServiceCollection. Unable to create an object of
>   type 'TodoContext'. For the different patterns supported at design
>   time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I read that but can't find helpfull for me can anyone help me?

Comment: Is that your full appsettings.json?

Comment: @Haytam Yes That is

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my problem first of all i changed my appsettings.json file as suggested and it look like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": { "todo": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Todo;Trusted_Connection=True;" },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

But it didn't fix the problem so i start checking startup.cs and change the way i inject  appsettings so my startup.cs file look like this:

```
        public IConfiguration _config { get; set; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        _config = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["todo"]));
    }
```

I inject Iconfiguration in startup constructor and define _config var and assign configuration to it after that i use **GetSection** to get connection string

Comment: Have you tried the way I have fetched connection string?

Answer (score 2):

You can try registering db context in this way as well:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connection")));
    ...
}
```

or you can manually register the db context:

```
services.AddTransient<TodoContext>();
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `GetConnectionString`, your `appsettings.json` should contain a section called **ConnectionStrings**, inside you'll need to have as a key the name of your connection (e.g. "todo") and value the actual connection string.

Example:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "todo": "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Todo;Trusted_Connection=True;"
},
-- Rest of your appsettings
```

Then you'll use it like this: `config.GetConnectionString("todo")`

Quoting from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getconnectionstring?view=aspnetcore-2.2), GetConnectionString is a:

> Shorthand for GetSection("ConnectionStrings")[name].

Comment: I Changed it but i think my main problem is in  **config** I think i inject it in wrong way

Answer (score 1):

Please Change you config to :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "connection": "Server=Yourserver;Database=DAWIDARI;Trusted_Connection=true;"
},
```

and call it in Startup.cs

```
 services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("connection")));
```

Comment: I Changed it but i think my main problem is in  **config** I think i inject it in wrong way